# How can I split Biblatex's \printbibliography over multiple pages, with different styles?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, fancyhdr, naming, splitbib

I am working on Latex document totalling 360 pages for group coursework at University. Part of the coursework, is that we have to have each of our names on each page, to which we contributed. I am using

```
\fancypagestyle{John Doe}
{
    \fancyhead[R]{John Doe}
}
```

Do this, then using on the pages which are our own work, the command:

```
\pagestyle{John Doe}
```

Easy to do this for all the pages in the document, except for the Biblography.

The command

```
\printbibliography
```

Seems to print the bibliography all in one chunk.

We need to add our names, two pages per name in the bibliography, so ideally something like

```
\pagestyle{John Doe}
\newpage
\newpage
\pagestyle{Tom}
\newpage
\newpage
\pagestyle{Jerry}
etc ...
```

However with the content being the content of the bibliography.

The bibliography is 24 pages long, and there are 12 members in the team.

How can we do this ?

Comment: See a concise one-line/option solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/914003/2535249.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `keywords` key in the bibliography field.

For example, you can annotate your `.bib` fields as follows:

```
@online{johnsfirst,
    title="John",
    month=November,
    date=2013,
    day=10,
    keywords={john},}
@online{johnssecond,
    title="John",
    month=November,
    date=2013,
    day=10,
    keywords={john},}
@online{tomsfirst,
    title="tom",
    month=November,
    date=2013,
    day=10,
    keywords={tom},}
@online{tomssecond,
    title="tom",
    month=November,
    date=2013,
    day=10,
    keywords={tom},}
@online{jerrysfirst,
    title="jerry",
    month=November,
    date=2013,
    day=10,
    keywords={jerry},}
@online{jerryssecond,
    title="jerry",
    month=November,
    date=2013,
    day=10,
    keywords={jerry},}
```

Then, in your file, you can use, for example

```
\printbibliography[title={john's contributions},keyword=john]
\printbibliography[title={tom's work},keyword=tom]
\printbibliography[title={jerry's stuff},keyword=jerry]
```

You might also like to look at `notkeyword` :)

Here's a complete `.tex` file, with [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) directives.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}          

\addbibresource{contributors}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={john's contributions},keyword=john]
\printbibliography[title={tom's work},keyword=tom]
\printbibliography[title={jerry's stuff},keyword=jerry]
\end{document}
```