# multiple citation categories in latex

Tags: bibtex

Edit: I have abandoned trying to fix it myself. My university didn't needed to have it explicitly split up, so I go with it how it is now...
Still thanks everyone, who tried to fix it.

I'm using TeXstudio and I'm writing a small document. I did some references I cite with the package 'cite', **but it is outdated and should no longer be used** . I now try to use biblatex, but struggle to find the right command for the following example. 
Does anyone know, how I can implement multiple reference titles?
(example)
List of literature
-Books
-Articles
-URLs
Has anyone came across a package or command that does the trick?
Update: This is how the main document looks like (left out unimportant parts).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}

\usepackage{biblatex}%[backend=bibtex]
\addbibresource{bib/bibliothek.bib}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    
\include{kapitel/Deckblatt}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{kapitel/start}
%THEORIE
\include{kapitel/Theorie/Theorie}
%PRAXIS
\include{kapitel/Praxis/Praxis}
%ANHANG
\part{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography[keyword=book,title={books}]
\printbibliography[keyword=url,title={urls}]
\printbibliography[keyword=article,title={articles}]
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

bib-file:
Every item looks like this(articles have the @article, etc.):

```
@BOOK {mooreh.l.1967,    
    author    = "Moore, H. L.",
    title     = "Laws of wages: an essay in statistical economies",
    publisher = "New York: A.M. Kelley",
    year      = "1967",
    note      = "Original 1911 veröffentlicht",
    keywords={book}}
```

Comment: Package `cite` is kind of *out of date*. The modern package `biblatex` can do easily what you want. But you need to chnge a few things in your document.

Comment: Well then I will edit my question, because I wasn't aware that cite seems to be some kind of relic of the past.  Do you have a good reference for biblatex where I could do these kind of multiple references?

Comment: The `biblatex` manual itself explains how to do this. The basic thing is that you call `\printbibliography[<options>]` several times, and filter your citations so that each call to to `\printbibliography` only prints a certain class of entries (e.g., using the options `type` and `nottype`, or `keyword` and `notkeyword`, `category` and `notcategory`, or a `filter`).

Comment: having answered this, it looks a lot like: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307517/how-can-i-split-biblatexs-printbibliography-over-multiple-pages-with-differen/307521#307521

Comment: You will have to read the following: http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Comment: By the way, package `ngerman` is also on the list of obsolete package for quite some time. A decade? Two?

Comment: @Johannes_B the golatex.de link doesn't explain the usage of multiple reference titles. I used ngerman, because it was used in a book / pdf published in 2013 - "LaTeX – eine Einführung und ein bisschen mehr ...". It had good examples on how to use basic stuff. So I didn't checked that, if ngerman is already obsolete.

Comment: Hm, strange. You said you are struggling to get it working but don't mention if bibliographies in general work. That is why i gave you the link. It is explained there. And it also contains *another* link that explains how you can separate bibliographies.

Comment: The mentioned book has mistakes. That happens.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete MWE using [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex), note the use of `keyword`.

[image]

You'll either need to run it with [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara), or else run the following:

```
pdflatex myfile
bibtex myfile
pdflatex myfile
pdflatex myfile
```

Here are the files:

### `myfile.tex`

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mybib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=book,title={books}]
\printbibliography[keyword=url,title={urls}]
\printbibliography[keyword=article,title={articles}]
\end{document}
```

### `mybib.bib`

```
@online{myfirstref,
    title="my first title goes here",
    url="first url goes here",
    keywords={book}}
@online{mysecondref,
    title="my second title goes here",
    url="second url goes here",
    keywords={article}}
@online{mythirdref,
    title="my third title goes here",
    url="third url goes here",
    keywords={url}}
```

Comment: While this is a perfectly fine answer, it seems odd to me to sort `@online` entries into 'books', 'articles', and so on. And the need to add keywords makes the task seem more onerous. Given the OP -- which names, books, articles, and 'URLs' -- I'd rather suggest using the `type`/`nottype` filter. At the very least, it saves the chore of adding keywords to all entries (whether by hand or via `\DeclareSourcemap`).

Comment: @jon It's just an example, which will also help a broader audience I guess, but I'm rather confused how to run these commands. It doesn't seem to be accepted inside of the *.tex-file, but I guess I have to read more into it...

Comment: Well I tried to include these commands, but it doesn't work. Even if I change the keywords from 'book' to BOOK, because in my generated file I use @BOOK and thought that was why TeXstudio couldn't find any sources, but didn't worked out either.

Comment: @Garamaru -- The example works. Part about changing to BOOK is irrelevant because `\printbibliography[keyword=article,...]` means `biblatex` is looking for entries that have the line `keywords={article}` in the `.bib` file. My point about `type` is how to filter based on `@<entrytype` (e.g., `@BOOK`). If 'it' can't find any sources, you are doing something different from the example ... but it is impossible to guess what that might be: more information is needed.

Comment: @jon feel free to post an example, I'll happily delete this

Comment: I updated my question, including the important code (some math and graphics related stuff and other things aren't included).  I also did the command, with a '| txs:///view' at the end, to get the document shown in TeXstudio. I also don't use the <entrytype> = online, because it would seem strange to me, why that has to be, when everything has the property of keyword.

Comment: What about keeping the answer as an example of `keyword`-filtering? I could add a `entry`-filtering example to complement it, or you could add it to this answer. It just requires changing/adding `.bib` entries that are (say) `@article` and `@book` (etc.) and then changing the `\printbibliography` commands.

Comment: @jon whatever you reckon :)