# Two separate bibliographies from one bibliography, items of one type in the second

Tags: bibliographies, xetex

I am using xelatex with bibtex for a PhD thesis. Using `\bibliography` command to build references at the end.

I do videogames research, and a common thing to do is to have a list of references, but then a separate 'ludography' just for the games/software cited in a paper.

At the moment I've just got my games in my references section  amongst all the publications etc. - since this was simple and straightforward. But I'd like to change this to the references/ludography split.

My game entries in my bibtext file are all `@misc`. This could be changed (there are other entries that come under `@misc` as well such as links and websites.)

So, how do I format my bibtex and use the `\bibliography` package to display references, and then a special 'ludography' just for the games?

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps the keywords key...? For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307521/6621

Comment: See *Bibliography Categories*,  §3.7.6  of the documentation, p.96.

Comment: Hi @Bernard, which documentation? The bibtex documentation only has 16 pages.

Comment: The  biblatex documentation (I thought I had seen the `biblatex` tag, sorry – anyway, I advise  using  biblatex+biber, as the latter understands utf8).

Comment: Is it easy to switch over? It's ACM format.

Comment: That's wonderful! Crossed over the biblatex, added keywords to the games entries in jabref, then printed bibliography using keyword and notkeyword in the options. This page also helped with the `\printbibliography` commands: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Getting_started_with_BibLaTeX

Shouldn't your comments have been answers? What's the 'right' thing for me to do now?